# XML data management with Windows Azure

Tags: xml, azure

I wrote a Windows Phone application and a framework that measures application usage. That framework produces XML (with information such as application information, phone details, phone settings, how does user use that application...).

I want to send those XMLs (from every phone) to Azure and merge them into a single XML that will be used for querying to extract some useful information of users' engagement.

As I am new to Azure I am asking you for steps I need to take to solve my problem. Is it perhaps better to map this xml to relational sql data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to skin a cat, however you may want to consider the following two possible architectures:

1. Using the Queue Storage API (see http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/queue-service/) push your Xml fragments as strings to storage queues and then work on the Xml fragments using a worker-role to aggregate the data.
2. Use the new mobile API to push data to Mobile Services tables (take a look at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-data-dotnet/ for more information), then use a worker-role to aggregate the data.